# Prove that the limit of $S_n = \frac{1}{5} (1-S_{n-1})$ is $\frac{1}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

An unrelated problem I was looking at resulted in me reaching this formula, $$S_n = \frac{1}{5} (1-S_{n-1})$$ with $S_1 = 0$.

It clearly converges to $\frac{1}{6}$, but I don't know how to prove it. What books (or topics) can I look in to for techniques and/or rigorous treatment of series like this?

Comment: prove that $ S_n -\frac 16 $ goes to Zero.

Comment: Notice that $$S_n=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5}S_{n-1}=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}S_{n-2}=\cdots=\sum^n_{i=1}(-1)^i\frac{1}{5^i}$$

Comment: @Alessandro yhea... you are right it's just a geometric series, you can make your comment and answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_n = -\dfrac{1}{5}S_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{5}$. An old trick is letting $S_n = T_n + c$, where $c$ is a constant that we will solve for. Plugging this into the equation we've got: $T_n + c = -\dfrac{1}{5}\left(T_{n-1}+c\right)+\dfrac{1}{5}= -\dfrac{1}{5}T_{n-1}+\dfrac{1-c}{5}$. Thus you want that $c = \dfrac{1-c}{5}\implies c = \dfrac{1}{6}\implies T_n = -\dfrac{1}{5}T_{n-1}= -\dfrac{1}{5}\left(-\dfrac{1}{5}T_{n-2}\right)=(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{5^{n-1}}T_1=(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{6\cdot 5^{n-1}}\implies T_n \to 0\implies S_n = T_n + \dfrac{1}{6} \to \dfrac{1}{6}$ as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

First note that if $x\in[0,1]$, $1/5(1-x)\in [0,1/5]$.  Therefore the sequence is bounded in $[0, 1/5]$.  If some subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converges to some limit $y$, then $y = 1/5(1-y)$, so $y = 1/6.$.  You can easily argue that every subsequential  limit is $1/6$, so the sequence converges to $1/6$.